# Hide ValidationError border & text on view with a custom Style

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, hide

In our project we have a `LookUp Base ViewModel` which has a `Required-Attribute` on the `SelectedItem` property. I have another View that uses one of the `child LookUps`, which should ignore the `Required`-attribute. I've already overridden the `IsValid` method in the ViewModel, so saving without caring about the `Required` works correctly, but unfortunately it's still showing the validation error on the view when I empty the `LookUp`:
[image]

I had a couple of possibilities:

1. Split the `LookUpBaseViewModel` into two childs that are also "BaseViewModels", one with the `RequiredAttribute` and one without. This works, but it seems like a bit too much work and a lot of extra classes for just a single view that doesn't need to show the validation errors on the View.
2. Replace the `RequiredAttribute` with a `RequiredIf-Attribute` and add a boolean `IsRequired` parameter to the Constructor. This doesn't work since we use `AutoFac` in our project, so we can't use a boolean parameter for the `ILookUpBaseViewModel`-interface implementation.
3. Add a style to the `LookUp-ContentControl` in the View to hide the `ValidationError border & text`. This seemed like the easiest solution on paper, and it also makes sense to just hide the unwanted `ValidationError border & text`.

So, my question, how do I make the style to hide the default WPF validation error (so the red border and the text behind it)? I'm a novice when it comes to styles, but this is what I've tried (and which doesn't do anything it seems):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="HideValidationErrorContentControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContentControl}}">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <!-- Empty -->
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <!-- Empty -->
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

With the style on my `LookUp-ContentControl` like this:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="MyLookup" Style="{StaticResource HideValidationErrorContentControlStyle}"/>
```

This is the result I want (even when a ValidationError would normally be shown):
[image]

Comment: Set Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" to the control where you do not need error red border.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it isn't your `LookUp-ContentControl` the one showing the error, but another control inside it. A `TextBox`, maybe?

Also, instead of leaving the `ErrorTemplate` empty, try to add an `AdornedElementPlaceholder`.

```
<Style x:Key="HideValidationErrorContentControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContentControl}}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It's likely this isn't needed, but better be safe than sorry.